# Does Material UI already support CSS Container Queries?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, container-queries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

`Container queries for CSS` are quite recent. Is `MUI 5.0` already capable of using them? Unfortunately, the `SxProps` do not have them. Is it possible to apply it in the MUI world without adding further `CSS` classes?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in their documentation or anywhere else.

If `MUI` does not currently provide that feature, is there perhaps another way to use them in `React` without adding extra `CSS` classes.
`React` doesn't support them as well with its `CSSProperties`.

Answer (score 4):

I just had luck with them! Like with some nested-ish properties, typescript support falls over a little, but nothing stopped me from trying 
However, I would couple this with the [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/container-query-polyfill) since at the time of writing, there was only a [76% usage on Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries).

I found my inspiration from a css tricks article: [A New Container Query Polyfill That Just Works](https://css-tricks.com/a-new-container-query-polyfill-that-just-works/). I used their method of adding the polyfill in a script tag on my `index.html` so it would only load if needed and wouldn't affect supporting browsers needlessly

Here's an example of how the css worked for me:

```
const Container = styled("div")(() => ({
  containerType: "size",
}))

const Card = styled("div")<{ borderColor: string }>(
  ({ theme, borderColor }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    ["@container (min-width: 700px)"]: {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  })
)

const Example: React.FC = () => {
return (
  <Container>
    <Card />
  </Container>
 )
}
```

Comment: Support is at 87% now 