# How to use css container query with mui?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, container-queries

I want to use css container query with mui. My code shall set the background to red, if the parent width is below 300px.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/f9pcj6?file=/Demo.tsx)

```
const Item = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  border: "solid 1px",
  padding: 100,
  ["@container (max-width: 300px)"]: {
    background: "red",
  },
}));

export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <div>
          <Item>I turn red for width smaller 300 </Item>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I may not be fully supported, you can use `@media` instead of `@container`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73714975/11095009 here is a similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're example is almost there -- to get the [Container Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) working, you need to add a [`container-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type) to whichever element you want to act as the container. *(The square brackets in your example are not needed.)*

With your example:

```
const Item = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  border: "solid 1px",
  padding: 100,
  "@container (min-width: 300px)": { // Corrected your query to min-width and removed brackets
    background: "red",
  },
}));

export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    {/* Adds containerType to the "container" element */}
    <div style={{ containerType: "inline-size" }}>
          <Item>I turn red for width smaller 300 </Item>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've added a few examples in this sandbox showing more example usage with MUI [Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) which produces the following based on the size available to the container.

**Large example - Content constrained to 100%:**

[image: large example]

**Smaller example - Content constrained to 300px:**

[image: smaller example]

**Smallest example - Content constrained to 250px:**

[image: smallest example]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-container-queries-gvl4fs
**Browser Support:** https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries